# Javascript Library to complement Razor MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've looked at a lot of JavaScript libraries, but as my JavaScript is not brilliant I find it difficult to dissect which ones will meet my requirements most effectively.

At the moment I have use view models and submit them back easy peasy. But I seem to be making more and more AJAX requests posting either the full model or some child/partial model when I don't want database persistence or just want to update a child. This normally ends up with a ton of jQuery selectors and some nasty string concatenation trying to match some model (when I use the serialize it doesn't treat GUIDs properly and some other things).

Everything at the moment works but seems a bit messy and was looking for a more elegant solution. In an ideal world I'd like to point it to my view models in my MVC project and have it replicate them as JavaScript models I can instantiate. Or am I totally missing the point of what these libraries are trying achieve, is this even what I should be trying to do?

If anyone could point me in the right direction or critique what I'm trying to achieve that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) which is a client-side MVVM framework, and even has a complementary project [KnockoutMVC](http://knockoutmvc.com/) for binding with MVC.

Comment: @PeterLea from the way you asked your question I'd be surprised if you did much research. There are lots of clientside binding frameworks out there, and ton's of comparisons. [Try googling client side binding frameworks](https://www.google.com/search?q=clientside+binding+framework+comparison&oq=clientside+binding+framework+comparison&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9824j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: sorry it came across that way, i had done all the knockout tutorials and looked at knockback, sproutcore and spine mainly. Although I could have used them all I just felt there must have been one would suit what I needed better. No one wants to invest a ton of time into something and then find out that they need to switch.  I'm marking yours as the correct answer as it looks like KnockoutMVC does everything I need it to, so thanks again.

Comment: Why downvote my four year old answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just replicate your server models on the client with the same properties, then any Javascript MV* framework should do the job.

However, it will NOT be done automatically, so you will have to write code. The framework will not generate a javascript object which maps to your C# object.

There are a number of client libraries which provide Models on the client and binding to a server endpoint. Here are some articles that I've found useful when comparing the functionality of the most popular and widely used frameworks:

- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/
- http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks
- http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

If it is only the Model part, you will find that you can use any framework. Choosing one depends on whether you want to use some additional functionality like Views, two-way binding, etc.

Comment: Really i'm just after the model binding back and forth so I can consume ajax calls easily without too much hassle, I not to do too much client side validation, so really its just about getting the model back to the server. +1 for the Steve Sanderson Link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some sort of web services to communicate with the server (like in C# XAML and WCF). For a project, I developed a web service description language for REST services which generates JavaScript/TypeScript web service client code:

http://jsdl.codeplex.com

I also made a library which provides a framework for KnockoutJS which allows to implement multiple view with a view model each and instantiate subviews directly in views (like in MVVM-XAML/WPF):

http://visto.codeplex.com

Using both libraries together is like implementing a WPF application with a WCF backend...